# How to model best an input/output model with neural network?

Tags: neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

The theme here is the use of neural network in learning time histories. 
Lets consider for clarity **Y** = f(**X**) where **X** is a vector 1xN and **Y**  1xN.

In most of the models I can find or test online, **X** is directly the time vectorised with regular timesteps (**X**=**T**). 
The prediction task performed on the time history is done therefore using the output Y, and using a sequence of this let say **Y**(i:i+Nsample) as an Neural Network input and then the output is **Y**(i+Nsample+1). Then the prediction is performed moving the window one step at the time ( i= i+1).

Now my question is the following. In the case where we have a vector X which is a generic function whose values are known, the problem to model with neural network is:

knowing **X**(i:i+Nsample+1) and **Y**(i:i+Nsample) we want to predict **Y**(i:i+Nsample+1)
then we can do i=i+1 and proceed forward.

What are the best solutions to design such a system, is there an example with Keras or other project from which I could be inspired?

I see several solutions but without being convinced.

a)Set a multidimensional vector (2xNsample) as input [X(i:i+Nsample ) ; Y(i-1:i+Nsample-1)] and predict **Y**(:i+Nsample) (treat the output as a second input)

b) set two separate lstm for X and Y and then concatenate them in some way

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to train a network in such a way that you give as input few X and Y it will be able to predict y* for an unseen x*. To me this seems exactly the training of a neural network

Comment: Yes it seems really easy but I can not find an example of an architecture working this way. All the examples with time series are with output only: knowing the past of a signal and trying to predict future of the same signal. In your response you are not assuming necessarily that the past is important, we could shuffle the vectors with same results. In my case I want to consider both past of X and Y as important though I just know the future of X.

Comment: RNN cells are working this way. They inherit the previous state and combine with new information from the new step. Examples and documentation: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#rnn

Comment: Are u trying to teach the network to predict a specific function or every function? in the second case i don't think it is possible

Comment: I added suggestions to I hope be more precise.